# Hungarian downloadable dictionary or word list

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, hungarian

I want to convert Hungarian words without accents into words with accents, for example `arvizturotukorfurogep` into `árvíztűrőtükörfúrógép`. I need a list of words for it in a data format (preferably JSON or XML), but I cannot find anything useful with search engines. I figured that maybe a Hungarian - English dictionary would be good for it too. Do you know of such a downloadable dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it looks like the best data source is wiktionary dumps. Here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/huwiktionary/latest/ the *huwiktionary-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2* contains the data I need. It is big, so I think a SAX parser is ideal for it.